# Connecting Multiple Sensors

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, multiplexer, output, input

I have 4 pairs of "LED + LDR" sensor. I need to be able to switch each of them on/off independently and take reading from the LDRs. To connect all of them to the microcontroller board, I would need 4 output pins for the LEDs, 4 output pins for the LDRs and 4 input pins for the LDRs. The output pins (also the power supply for the components) turn the LEDs and LDRs on/off while the input pins measure the current/voltage from the LDRs. **My microcontroller board has only 12 input/output pins, how do I minimize the pins usage?** I know the LDRs can be connected to a single input pin via a multiplexer but how do I connect the output pins to the components?
A schematic diagram would be very convenient. Thanks.

Comment: As far as i can tell, you need 8 pins. 4 to turn on/off LED+LDR pairs. 4 LDR inputs. So where's the constraint?

Comment: Yes that works. But I need to save as much pins as possible, I need to connect many other components to the microcontroller board as well.

Comment: Okay so you can save 3 pins by multiplexing the input. Now you can certainly employ a shift register to turn on/off the LED+LDR pairs. (THAT'S A GUESS!). If the above is correct, You might end up using only 4 pins for the pairs.

Comment: Do you need an analog measurement?  If not, then it's relatively easy to use 2 different kinds of shift registers, one for digital inputs and one for digital outputs, daisy-chained as far as you want to go, all controlled by 4 pins: Bit Clock, Data In, Data Out, and Set Data.  An almost perfect match for a SPI peripheral.  If you need analog, you *might* be able to get a SPI-based ADC on the same bus as well (no additional pins), but you also have to consider what the shift registers do while you're accessing the ADC and vice-versa.  You could get around that by using a second chip-select.

Comment: Or perhaps you could charlieplex the LED's.  (google that)

Comment: So they definitely cannot be operated one at a time? You must have multiple active at once?

Comment: @AaronD The outputs can be digital (i.e. high=5v; low=0v). But inputs are used for current/voltage measurements, they have to be analog and the microcontroller's input/output pins are analog by default. I need to ask though, can a shift register and/or multiplexer take analog input and provide analog output?

Comment: @Daniel There are 2^4 possibilities which include only one of them operating at one time.

Comment: @UmarZain Shift registers, no.  They're digital.  Multiplexers, sometimes.  See my comment to your answer.

Comment: Kind of over the top, but you could also use one GPIO to multiple FETs with different threshold voltages/different dividers. Then you could have one on, two on, three on depending on the output of the micro. If this is a micro with an DAC, then just change the output voltage to match the corresponding LED FET... yeah I wouldn't do it either.

Answer (score 1):

[image: IMG]

I came up with this circuit. 4 pins are used.
Note: I didn't include the clock connection for simplicity. The microcontroller board has a dedicated output pin of its clock, hence this would not affect the amount of input/output pins used up.

Comment: Looks good to me.  Actually, I'm pretty sure you can get an 8x2 analog mux/demux that does all of that on one chip.  It has two 4x1 circuits in it that can pass current in both directions, and that share the 2 select pins.  No clock required, but try to set the current to zero before switching.  I've stressed these chips to the point of latent failure by switching them with current.

Comment: @UmarZain This does not fulfill your requirement to have all combinations (2^4 as you mentioned) available. With this configuration, you can select one at a time.

Comment: @Daniel My idea is to turn on and read current from the sensor(s) one at a time but switching between them quickly and repetitively. For example if I want to use only Sensor1 and Sensor4, I would provide (via pins AO1 & AO2) an input of 00 to the mux and demux for 1ms, then 11 for 1ms, then 00 for 1ms, then 11 for 1ms...on and on until I need a different sensor combination. It might be less hassling with shift registers but I won't be able to get analog readings directly and faster. I can't think of other methods.